# GET Data empty in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

Hi I am new to Laravel and so far I made good progress. Right now my head is blocked now and I need some direction or help, please.

I am getting data from radio button but GET Data is empty. I need to fill-in this data (pay) into an exist DB and I am getting "Creating default object from empty value" and I agree with Laravel :) I guess, my lack of knowledge is blocking me here.

Thanks.

This is the GET and POST data

```
GET Data empty
POST Data
_token = "72nrnI7Y7xuIQJe6LZPLGLzNsAv6ZZbY29zkjcIr"
pay = "CC"`
```

This is the Model

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;
use Auth;
class DAddress extends Model
{
 protected $table='dAddress';
 protected $fillable = ['payment_method'];
 public function createPay()
 {
   $user = Auth::user();
   $order = $user->daddress()->create([
   'payment_method' => paymentMethod()
    ]);
 }
}
```

This is the Controller

```
public function paymentMethod(Request $request) {
    $address->payment_method = $request->pay;
    DAddress::createPay();
    Cart::destroy();
    return redirect('abc');
}
```

This is where I get the HTML data

```
<form action="{{url('/paymentMethod')}}" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}" name="_token"/>

<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- First name -->
            <input type="radio"  class="form-control"  name="pay" 
            value="CC"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i> Credit Card
            <br>  <br>
            <input type="radio"  class="form-control"  name="pay" 
            value="PP"><i class="fa fa-paypal"></i> Paypal
            <br>  <br>
            <input type="radio"  class="form-control"  name="pay" 
            value="BT"><i class="fa fa-university"></i>  Bank Transfer
        </div>
</div>  
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Move to Last Page" />
```

This is the User.php I added below function.

```
public function daddress()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DAddress::class);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML form where you are getting data from too? Is the field in the form named "pay", and `$request->pay` is empty within your `paymentMethod`?

Comment: I edited HTML form. Simply I am getting from a form. Yes the radio buttons named "pay" . I believe it's empty that Laravel is giving me "creating default object from empty value".

Answer (score 0):

i do not understand what you are trying to do with this line $address->payment_method = $request->pay;
when you say $address->payment_method, what is the $address object holding and where is payment_method you are trying to access, why not do something like this $payment_method = $request->pay, except is you are setting $payment_method as a global variable

Comment: $address->payment_method (is one of the column in created table)  = $request->pay (is the data I am getting from form); I am trying to inject this data into field that already created. If I create object it registers into new field. I hope I am clear with my explanation.

Comment: But $address doesnt exist... how you will assign a value?

Comment: DAddress::createPay(); is imposible to use because createPay is not static method

Comment: Why don use new DAddress() in your controller... or $address = Auth::user()->daddress(); and after $address->payment_method = ....

Comment: There are a few programming concepts errors, please try to analice

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the laravel create method you could do something like this $payment_method= App\createPay::create(['payment_method' => $request->pay]);
else you could instantiate you model like

```
$pay =createPay();
$pay->payment_method=$request->pay;
$pay->save();
```

i would have love you logic to be in the controller, i  would have done something like this in my controller
public function createPay(Request $request){

```
 $user = Auth::user();
$id=$user->id;
$payment=createPay::find($id);
$payment->payment_method=$request->pay;
$payment->save();
return redirect('abc');
```

}

i used laravel eloquent here, that is if you want to update a record, i don't know if this is close to what you want.

Comment: I tried like this -------> public function paymentMethod(Request $request)
      {               
        $pay =createPay();
        $pay->payment_method=$request->pay;
        $pay->save();
        DAddress::createPay();
        Cart::destroy();
        return redirect('abc');
      }

Comment: I got  this "Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\createPay()" so I need to check why it refers to Controller ?

Comment: please what did you get when you ran it that way?

Comment: you need to add "use App\createPay" at the top of the controller

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added but i got same result. If i may ask, why we need to add "App\createPay"  ? Is "createPay" not just a function ?

Comment: is it the Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\createPay() error you got or the radio returning empty again?

Comment: when you add " use App\createPay" you make the model class available for the controller by given the fully qualified path to it

Comment: also the createPay should be your model class

Comment: I thought the same. I tried but I got same result :(   my model is DAddress  (you can see above), I added (use App\DAddress)into Controller where "paymentMethod" function is. All i need to know who to take a value (from a radio button) and add inject to existed filed in the table.

Comment: Opps!! sorry for putting you into more stress, please replace the createPay with DAddress which is your model, like so

Comment: I missed your question. Yes, i got the same error the radio returning is not empty. It is always got the data like this GET Data empty 
POST Data
_token = "72nrnI7Y7xuIQJe6LZPLGLzNsAv6ZZbY29zkjcIr"
pay = "CC"

Comment: use App\DAddress; public function createPay(Request $request){ $pay=DAddress(); $pay->payment_method = $request->pay; $pay->save(); return redirect('abc');}

Comment: please your route should be Route::post and not Route::get, please check that too

Comment: Hi i am sorry but I am even more confused because when I change the codes according to your suggestions my "paymentMethod" function in "DAddress" gave me an error. My route is post.

Comment: I think in the model i need to get the data and put it here "paymentMethod()" so should be something like this 'payment_method' => The data from the form.

Comment: just for debugging purpose please can you try it like this, your model should look like this: namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;
use Auth;
class DAddress extends Model
{
 protected $table='dAddress';
 protected $fillable = ['payment_method'];
 
}

Comment: and your controller like this: public function paymentMethod(Request $request) { $user = Auth::user();
   $order = $user->daddress()->create([
   'payment_method' => $request->pay]);
    Cart::destroy();
    return redirect('abc');
}, let me get your feedback when you run it please

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried, I can save the data  but it created new row. I need to add this data into field which existed row. How can I do that ?

Comment: public function paymentMethod(Request $request){$id=Auth::user()->id; $order=DAddress::find($id); $order->payment_method=$request->pay; $order->save(); Cart::destroy(); return redirect('abc');}, please try the code and get back to me

Comment: for this to work, there must be a relationship between the user table and dAddress, you might consider having user_id in the dAddress table if you dont have one and save the user id to it.

Comment: Hi, I found a solution ! Replaced "create" function with "update" that's was all. Now it is working like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help.